# Removing Stopwords from a string in spark

Tags: regex, scala, stop-words

Hi I want to remove stopwords in from a string in Spark.

Say I have input string **"Hello-people"**, then I want the output to be **(hello people)** but I am getting it as **(hellopeople)**

My code is :

```
def processLine(s: String, stopWords: Set[String]): Seq[String] = {   
  s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+")
  s.filter(!stopWords.contains(_))
  s.toSeq
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def processLine(s: String, stopWords: Set[String]): Seq[String] = {

    s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", " ")
      .toLowerCase()
      .split("\s+")
      .filter(!stopWords.contains(_)).toSeq
}
```

There's only one change, in the replaceAll, " " instead of ""